# Solving equations with high level exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well I am doing my homework, and I can't seem to figure out how to solve this one:

> Find all solutions, real and complex, of the equation. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If there is no solution, enter NO SOLUTION.)
>       $x^9 + x^8 + x^7 = 0$

Normally, I would use wolframalpha to get the answer and check if it is right, because I am doing an online assignment, but I don't know how to do this, and wolframalpha's answers are wrong... Could someone explain to me how to do this, and if not, at least the answers?

**EDIT:**

I already turned in the assignment with this one wrong, but I don't know why the other solution didn't work... I probably put it in wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Note: 
    $$x^9 + x^8 + x^7 = 0 \;\; \iff \;\;x^7(x^2+x+1)=0.$$

Simply solve the equations $x^7=0$ and $x^2+x+1=0.$

No need for WolframAlpha: simply use the quadratic formula to obtain solutions to the second equation.

You'll get one real and two complex (non-real) solutions.

Comment: Recall: [Quadratic Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormula.html)

Comment: Regarding your edit: Was this helpful to understand where you may have gone wrong (not knowing what answers you submitted...) You should have gotten $\,x_1 = 0,\;$ as a solution, and using the quadratic formula: $\, x_2 = \dfrac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2},\;x_3 = \dfrac{-1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, as the other two solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You could write the equation as
\begin{equation*}
x^7(x^2+x+1)=0.
\end{equation*}
Now, solve the equation $x^7=0$ and $x^2+x+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Look, $x = 0$ is definitely a solution. So you want to find solutions $x \ne 0$. Divide by $x^7$...

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that Wolfram Alpha's solutions $\left\{\text{$\color{blue}{x_\mathrm{I} = 0}$, $\color{green}{x_\mathrm{II} = (-1)^{2/3}}$, $\color{red}{x_\mathrm{III} = -\sqrt[3]{-1}}$} \right\}$ are indeed correct.

As others already have noted, the equation can be factorized into $x^7(x^2+x+1)=0$. Clearly, the first factor $x^7=0$ has only the root $\color{blue}{x_1 = 0 = x_\mathrm{I}}$. By the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula#Quadratic_formula), the second factor $x^2+x+1=0$ has the two roots $x_{\color{green}{2},\color{red}{3}} = \dfrac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. Now, recall [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula). We see that $e^{i\pi} = \cos \pi + i\sin \pi = -1$, so
\begin{equation*}
\color{green}{x_\mathrm{II} = (-1)^{2/3} = e^{i2\pi/3} = \,\underbrace{\cos \frac{2\pi}{3}}_{-1/2} + i\,\underbrace{\sin \frac{2\pi}{3}}_{\sqrt{3}/2} = x_2}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\color{red}{x_\mathrm{III} = -\sqrt[3]{-1} = -e^{i\pi/3} = -\,\underbrace{\cos \frac{\pi}{3}}_{1/2} - i\,\underbrace{\sin \frac{\pi}{3}}_{\sqrt{3}/2} = x_3}.
\end{equation*}
Hence Wolfram Alpha's solutions are also correct.

Comment: Wolfram's "solutions" are not solutions at all. They're only restatement of the question.